# C++ Using unsigned char instead of typedef unsigned __int8

Tags: c++, class, typedef, encryption

I am using a class that I like very much:

```
#pragma once
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "xorcipher.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned __int8 BYTE;

    vector<BYTE>m_Key;

    CXORcipher::CXORcipher()
    {   
        m_Key.push_back(0x55);
        m_Key.push_back(0xae);
        m_Key.push_back(0x8c);
        m_Key.push_back(0x14);
    }
    CXORcipher::~CXORcipher()
    {
    }

    vector<BYTE> xor_encryptdecrypt(const vector<BYTE>&uInput)
    {
        vector<BYTE> ret;
        ret.reserve(uInput.size());

        vector<BYTE>::const_iterator keyIterator = m_Key.begin();

        for(vector<BYTE>::const_iterator inputIterator = uInput.begin(); inputIterator != uInput.end(); ++ inputIterator)
        {
            ret.push_back(*inputIterator ^ *keyIterator);

            // advance the key iterator, wrapping to begin.
            if(++ keyIterator == m_Key.end())
            {
                keyIterator = m_Key.begin();
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

However, I would like to feed a vector of unsigned char instead of the typedef.
I am not really firm with C++ yet, and I am afraid to mess something up.

Could somebody tell me what I can do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it: `vector<BYTE>` is already a `vector<unsigned char>`. Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: `typedef`'s are "weak". If you `typedef` `A` as `B` you can use `A` and `B` interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would right away when you pass a vector, because BYTE is through the typedef defined as __int8, which in my opionion is the same as an unsigned char.

What you otherwise can do:

1. Replace all occurences of BYTE to unsigned char (this is safe for your code)
2. Create a templatized version of the CXORcipher class, which works with different data types.

Comment: Unfortunately, a simple replacement does not work for me. The problematic line is this one:     for(vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator inputIterator = uInput.begin(); inputIterator != uInput.end(); ++ inputIterator) I don't have any iterator for unsigned char.

Comment: What's the error message? Did you also change uInput to const vector<unsigned char>& ?

Answer (score 2):

You could #include  and use `uint8_t`, which is an 8-bit unsigned integer, commonly referred to as `unsigned char`.

Example:

```
#include <cstdint>
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
```

Answer (score 2):

`__int8` seems to be a Microsoft-specific keyword. (It's not a `typedef`; if it were `unsigned __int8` would be a syntax error.)

A reasonable way to define a `byte` or `BYTE` type is as a typedef for `unsigned char`. Or you can just use `unsigned char` directly without a `typedef`; any C or C++ programmer will recognize it as an unsigned type with a size of exactly 1 byte.

You can use `uint8_t`, defined in `<cstdint>`, *if* you're willing to assume `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which is very common but not universal. (A "byte" in C and C++ is the size of a `char`, which is *at least* 8 bits but can be more.)

I don't know whether `unsigned char` and `unsigned __int8` are the same type, but I suspect they are. In any case, using `__int8` makes your code non-portable. (That's not necessarily a fatal flaw if you have no need to port it to non-Microsoft platforms, but more people will be able to help you with standard C++ than with Microsoft-specific C++.)

In a comment on [Matthias247's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322348/827263), you wrote:

> Unfortunately, a simple replacement does not work for me. The
>   problematic line is this one: `for(vector<unsigned
>   char>::const_iterator inputIterator = uInput.begin(); inputIterator !=
>   uInput.end(); ++ inputIterator)` I don't have any iterator for
>   `unsigned char`.

Please update your question, adding code that exhibits the problem and the exact error message. (Don't delete the existing code, since you already have answers that refer to it.)